# Splitting with a string with special characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a HTML code from which I want to remove some certain tags. I am trying to do without parsing it and retriving tags. So, I got the whole HTML code in a string. I want to remove the following tags:

```
<cite>www.youtube.com/watch?v=
```

For this, I am using:

```
array=htmlCode.split("<cite>www.youtube.com/watch?v=");
```

This tag occurs many times. But when I split, I don't get substring in my array, just got a single string of full code. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should use replace method. By the way the you are not putting correct param for split.

Comment: replace?? And why is it wrong? I also tried by putting escape on each special character [array=htmlCode.split("\\<cite\\>www\\.youtube\\.com\\/watch\\?v\\=");]  this also not working.

Comment: try replace if u know exactly which tag u want to remove

Comment: You should read example of split method. meanwhile, this method splits the string in as many string as the looking string found. In your case you can use htmlCode.split(">").

Comment: U can use Scanner class if u dont want split. Check for the documentation for the same

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to escape `.` and `?` in regex, because they have special meanings. Normally, you would do it with single backslash, `\`. But, we are in the middle of a string and `\` unfortunately has a special meaning inside quotation marks too. So, we have to escape it again, that's why we need two backslashes, `\\`.
2. [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a method you are looking for.

Example:

```
String htmlCode = "START<cite>www.youtube.com/watch?v=END";
String result = htmlCode.replaceAll("<cite>www\\.youtube\\.com/watch\\?v=", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/h5ylZe):

```
STARTEND
```

Bonus:

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) is a handy tool for testing regular expressions.

Comment: Good idea. But the response is full HTML code. If i replace it with blank, I will get no keyword to fetch xD. So, I think I can replace it with some other unique string. That will work. :D